# Google Sheet use ArrayFormula with textjoin

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, array-formulas, textjoin

I have [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1495WOcKzLXAlkfzOHHdjQBKeHg3RJwPcmkO92WHNv8g/edit?usp=sharing) with a list of items. I want to concat the columns with products `B:K` into one column and to automatically run this function for all non-empty rows.
I've tried to use `arrayformula` with `textjoin`, but it just copies the same rows multiple times.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in cell `L1`:

```
=arrayformula({"Name","Items";A2:A,regexreplace(regexreplace(trim(flatten(query(transpose(B2:K)&",","",9^9))),"[\ ,]+$",),",\ ",",")})
```

[image]

Or this to not remove spaces after the commas:

```
=arrayformula({"Name","Items";A2:A,regexreplace(trim(flatten(query(transpose(B2:K)&",","",9^9))),"[\ ,]+$",)})
```

If you've got spaces in your product names, or gaps between products (horizontally), then use:

```
=arrayformula({"Name","Items";A2:A,regexreplace(regexreplace(trim(flatten(query(transpose(B2:K)&",","",9^9))),"[,\ ]{2,}",", "),"[,\ ]+$",)})
```

Comment: I suggest `=arrayformula(REGEXREPLACE(flatten(query(transpose(B2:K)&", ",,columns(B2:K))),"[\, ]+$",))` to get a space after each comman as required

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `textjoin` inside `arrayformula`.

Here is the custom function you can use instead:

```
function array_text_join(data) {
  const result = data.map(row=>{
    const isEmptRow = !row.some(cell=>cell !== "")
    return [isEmptRow? undefined: row.filter(cell=>cell!=="").join(",")]
  })
  return result
}
```

Just place it into L2 `=array_text_join(A2:K)`

Answer (score 1):

simple but it remains a comma at the end, in L2

```
=flatten(query(transpose(arrayformula(if(B2:K="","",B2:K&", "))),,COLUMNS(B2:K)))
```